# sap.m.upload.UploadSet: how to display illustrated message in no data?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I write an attachment using the control `sap.m.upload.UploadSet`.

When there is no attachment, it dispalys an icon with message like this:
[image: Empty UploadSet with icon]

In a sample from https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.upload.UploadSet, however, it displays with an illustrated message like that:
[image: Empty UploadSet with illustration message]

I compared the XML and JS code from the sample but couldn't find anything special.

How could I achieve the same effect like the sample from Demo Kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st screenshot shows the control `sap.m.upload.UploadSet` from an older UI5 version.

- Since UI5 1.104 ([commit: `d33e404`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d33e40490b55cd40fa319917e679f14a33910bea)), `UploadSet` uses its own instance of `sap.m.IllustratedMessage` internally for the *no data* area by design.
- Since UI5 1.117 ([commit: `2af8989`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/2af8989c90f6318b8bb352922361d0719d6e22fd)), `UploadSet` provides the property `noDataIllustrationType` to which you can [assign your own `IllustratedMessageType`.](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.IllustratedMessageType)

Migrate to one of the the next [maintained UI5 versions](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html).

Comment: you are right. first screen shot is UI5 1.102